# Event and Data Handling Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js and I have trouble on answering my code activities:

So the menu button would open selections from the drop down box upon clicking, and when you click any of the selections, it would go back to the menu button

index.js

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: () => {
        {return {menuClick: true}}
    },
    methods: {
      methodClick(e){
          console.log(event.target.value)
      }  
    },
    template: `
      <div @click="methodClick">
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' v-if="methodClick">Open</a>
        <ul class='dropdown-content'v-else="!methodClick">
          <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    `
});
```

index.html

```
<!--Don't edit this!  Change to the index.js file (click on the link on the left side) and edit that file-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<style>.dropdown-content{ display: block !important; opacity: 1 !important; }</style>
<div id="root">
</div>
<!--Don't edit this!  Change to the index.js file (click on the link on the left side) and edit that file-->
```

When I console log it, it just says it is undefined.

Comment: hey, welcome to SO. First of all, I think you are checking the wrong variable. v-if="methodClick" should be v-if="menuClick" right? And your data function should return those values. Now you aren't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made use of the attribute 'menuClick'

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: () => {
        return {menuClick: false} // changes added
    },
    methods: {
      methodClick(e){
          console.log(event.target.value);
          this.menuClick = !this.menuClick; // changes added

      }  
    },
    template: `
      <div @click="methodClick">
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' v-if="!menuClick">Open</a> // changes added
        <ul class='dropdown-content' v-else> // changes added
          <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    `
});
```